# Can a Windows desktop app work also on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, mobile, windows-phone

I have a windows desktop app done in VB. Can I have same app to work on windows mobile also?

As far as I know windows mobile development is different and windows desktop development is different. Can we have 1 single app that works for both(windows mobile & windows desktop)?

I have developed a windows mobile app before and I had done it through Visual studio(Xaml and C#).
I have also worked with windows desktop app visual studio(c#).

If it is possible to have single app for both mobile and desktop then will the existing VB.net app will work? Or do I have to build a separate app from scratch?

Comment: No. Desktop application and windows application is different. Desktop application has .exe extension while mobile application has .xap extension

Comment: There are new Technologies now with Windows 10 that will allow universal apps, but definitely they are not related with desktop application and to use them you will rewrite your application. More so,  applications for mobile, and touch devices have a very long series of limitations for data managing and interop with the devices or other applications.

Comment: Please explain downvote

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you mean by "Windows Mobile".

If you mean the old Windows that runs on old mobile devices called "Windows Mobile", then yes, you can have a single app for desktop and mobile providing you use .NET Compact Framework.

But if by "Windows Mobile" you mean "Windows Phone", then no. You cannot have a WPF/WinForms application that can run on Windows Phone devices. However, you can develop Windows Store app (or Universal Application for Windows 10) using Windows Runtime, that will run on desktop, tablet or phone.

[What is Universal Windows Application?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn726767.aspx)

Comment: By "Windows mobile" I mean windows phone 8 and higher.

Comment: Then (as stated in my answer) it is not possible to have WinForms or WPF app that runs on both desktop and Windows Phone. If you want to develop an application that runs on both devices (and also tablets, etc.) you have build your application with Windows Runtime API (for Windows 8.x) or Universal Windows Apps API (Windows 10) - see https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop